# iterate div with textboxes and change id using javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I try to iterate through each textbox placed in `<div class="col-md-2">` using javascript in order to change their Id's like this..

```
    function iterateBoxesAndSetUniqueIds() {

    var childDivs = document.getElementById('subContent').children;
    //alert(childDivs.length);

    for( i=0; i< childDivs.length; i++ )
    {
        var el = children[i];
        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Key'; // 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Key';

        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.StartDate'; 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.StartDate';

        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.EndDate'; 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.EndDate';

        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.Description'; 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.Description';
    }

<div id="divcontent">
<div class="form-group" id="subContent">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Key" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.StartDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.EndDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.Description" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group" id="subContent">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Key" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.StartDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.EndDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.Description" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
```

The result I'm looking for is this...

```
<div id="divcontent">
<div class="form-group" id="subContent">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Key" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.StartDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.EndDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.Description" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group" id="subContent">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[1].Key" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[1].Value.StartDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[1].Value.EndDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" name="events[1].Value.Description" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
```

But I get a "ReferenceError: children is not defined" error in the javascript when running the javascript function. Can anyone please help out?

**UPDATE**
After changing the function the result now look like this..

```
<div id="divcontent">

<div class="form-group" id="subContent">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="events[0].Value.Description">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Key" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" id="events[1].Value.Description">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.StartDate" value="">
    </div><div class="col-md-2" id="events[2].Value.Description">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.EndDate" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" id="events[3].Value.Description">
      <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.Description" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" id="events[4].Value.Description">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

when using this code..

```
    function iterateBoxesAndSetUniqueIds() {

    var childDivs = document.getElementById('subContent').children;
    //alert(childDivs.length);

    for( i=0; i< childDivs.length; i++ )
    {
        var el = childDivs[i];
        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Key'; // 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Key';

        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.StartDate'; 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.StartDate';

        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.EndDate'; 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.EndDate';

        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.Description'; 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.Description';
    }
```

Comment: Please turn this into a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the form of a [runnable Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), so we can reproduce the issue right from the question. Cheers!

Comment: I have updated my answer below to address some more issues with your original code. Let me know if you run into any more issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the cause of `ReferenceError: children` is not defined is this code

```
 var el = children[i];
```

If you change that to:

```
var el = childDivs[i];
```

You get a result where it changes 0,1,2,3,4 for the first ONLY THE FIRST subContent, which is not what you really want.

So what you would like to do is to use `querySelector` to get all subContents. From there we could change each individual content of that specific subContent.

Assuming there is only 4 fields for each subContent this is your solution

```js
     function iterateBoxesAndSetUniqueIds() {

    var subContents = document.querySelectorAll("#subContent")

    //LOOPS OVER ALL SUBCONTENTS
    for (i = 0; i < subContents.length; i++) {
        var children = subContents[i].children
        console.log(children)
        children[0].children[0].name = 'events[' + i + '].Key';
        children[1].children[0].name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.StartDate';
        children[2].children[0].name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.EndDate';
        children[3].children[0].name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.Description';
    }
}
```

Let me explain this code:

1. Get all the subContents
2. For each subcontent I will get all its children
3. for each children aka `<div class="col-md-2">` has 1 children `input field` so I use `children[0]` so I change the name of that

Comment: If id has to be changed then the code should also have `children[0].children[0].id = children[0].children[0].name = 'events[' + i + '].Key';]`

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop you have `children[i]` change this to `childDivs[i]`.

You are referencing a variable `children` that does not exist in your loop. You need to access each value held in the nodeList `childDivs`

To solve the second issue you need to use the iteration index `i` as a vraiable rather than passing it in as a string. E.g:

```
for( i=0; i< childDivs.length; i++ )
{
    var el = childDivs[i];
    el.name = events[i].Key; // 
    el.id = events[i].Key;

    el.name = events[i].Value.StartDate; 
    el.id = events[i].Value.StartDate;

    el.name = events[i].Value.EndDate; 
    el.id = events[i].Value.EndDate;

    el.name = events[i].Value.Description; 
    el.id = events[i].Value.Description;
}
```

Although in each iteration of the loop you are now setting name and id differently 4 times. You need to think what value you want to set the id and the name too and just do it once. E.g:

```
for( i=0; i< childDivs.length; i++ ) {
    var el = childDivs[i];

    el.name = events[i].Key;
    el.id = events[i].Key;
}
```

Make sure to change `events[i].Key` to the correct property you want to use. Also I have got rid of the quotes around `events[i].Key` as these are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the var children and it doesn't exist. The correct var is childDivs. Here is the correction:

```
function iterateBoxesAndSetUniqueIds() {

var childDivs = document.getElementById('subContent').children;
//alert(childDivs.length);

for( i=0; i< childDivs.length; i++ )
{
    var el = childDivs[i];
    el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Key'; // 
    el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Key';

    el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.StartDate'; 
    el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.StartDate';

    el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.EndDate'; 
    el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.EndDate';

    el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.Description'; 
    el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.Description';
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm sorry that changed the id of the div instead of the textboxes. I'm looking for a way to give textbox in div called subContent  the same unique id.